# Debug C++ console application in Qt Creator on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, qt, debugging, lldb

I wrote a simple console application, and tried to debug it. But when I start debugging, in application output appears this message: `Run in Terminal is not supported with the LLDB backend.`.
I use Qt Creator 4.1.0 on Mac OS X 10.11.

Here is an example of code that I tried to debug:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a;
    cin >> a;

    cout << "a^2 = " << a * a;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also met this problem.
If I create a new C/C++ (Non-Qt project), the debugger doesn't work. However, if I create a Qt console project, the debugger works well.

Answer (score 0):

There is the gdb debbugger wich is the GNU debbugger.
Here there is a [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gnu_debugger/index.htm)